# Disable https in vue cli production build

Tags: typescript, vue.js, webpack, babeljs, vue-cli-3

I have a vue project created from [vue-cli](https://cli.vuejs.org/)

I am consuming my API that is not secured at the moment so I must use http.

The problem is when I do `yarn build` vue(or babel, typescript or webpack) replaces all of my http endpoints with https

My question: **How to force HTTP in production build?**

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was so focused on finding the problem that I didn't realise I was the problem.

In my configuration of the Axios I set HTTPS if NODE_ENV=production

and so I was always building with HTTPS instead of HTTP